# ReactJS mui/material Topography value error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, topography

```
interface CardTableRowInterface {
  key: string;
  label?: string;
  value?: (data: any) => React.ReactElement;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export interface CardTableProps extends CardTableStyleProps {
  data: Record<string, unknown>;
  rows: Array<CardTableRowInterface | string>;
  size?: "large" | "medium";
  disableBlankRows?: boolean;
  CardHeaderProps?: CardHeaderProps;
}

const CardTable: React.FC<CardTableProps> = (props) => {
  const { data, rows, size = "medium", disableBlankRows, ...rest } = props;
  const isLarge = size === "large";
  return (
    <StyledTable {...rest}>
      <TableBody>
        {rows.map((row) => {
          const key = typeof row === "object" ? row.key : row;
          const label =
            typeof row === "object"
              ? getLabelFromKey(row.label || key)
              : getLabelFromKey(row);
          const value =
            typeof row === "object" && typeof row.value === "function"
              ? row.value(data)
              : get(data, key);

          if (!value && disableBlankRows) return;

          return (
            <TableRow key={key}>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableColumnHeaderCell}>
                <Typography variant={isLarge ? "h5" : "h6"}>{label}</Typography>
              </TableCell>

              <TableCell>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                  {value}
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </StyledTable>
  );
};
```

Error:

```
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "left" | "center" | "right" | "inherit" | "justify"; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...>; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TypographyTypeMap<{}, "span">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

  81 |               <TableCell>
  82 |                 <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
> 83 |                   {value}
     |                   ^
  84 |                 </Typography>
  85 |               </TableCell>
  86 |             </TableRow>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `value` should be string type or resolvable value. It should not be an object or array type to pass to react node. You can console log the value and check the type of value.

Comment: I can't even build. How to `console.log`?

Comment: before return statement write `console.log(value);`  like below:

`if (!value && disableBlankRows) return;
           console.log(value); 
          return (`

Comment: How does that help a build time error?

Comment: to check the value held by the `value` variable, you need to console that `value` variable. so only for console, you can remove your return statement HTML/JSX code which has the error while building.